# Opening a program through the terminal in Kali Linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess, command

Trying to make it not a hassle to open pyCharm in Kali Linux. I've been following an online class, and the way to open pyCharm is to navigate to the `.sh` file and open it. I tried automating the process using the subprocess module, but it gives the error:

> no such file or directory: 'cd': 'cd'

My code:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cd")
subprocess.call("cd", "Downloads/pycharm-community-2019.2.3/bin")
subprocess.call("/.pycharm.sh")
```

Comment: `cd` is not an executable, it's a function built into the shell (i.e. bash, zsh etc). You should use `os.chdir` instead

Answer (score 0):

set the shell to True:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cd", shell=True)
subprocess.call("cd", "Downloads/pycharm-community-2019.2.3/bin", shell=True)
subprocess.call("/.pycharm.sh", shell=True)
 #it is "./pycharm.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

**import subprocess

subprocess.call("cd", "Downloads/pycharm-community-2019.2.3/bin", shell=True)
subprocess.call("./pycharm.sh", shell=True)**

instead of "Downloads/pycharm-community-2019.2.3/bin" path, give full path of pycharm.sh file
Also there maybe error in execution of this shellscript file.if it's happening then you should first change file permissions and give executable permissions to this shellscript file which can be given by **chmod +x pycharm.sh**